# Fragments attached to a parent activity and back button

Tags: android, android-fragments

I would like to ask something about BackStackFragments. Let us suppose we have 2 buttons in an app. When each on them is clicked the a new fragment starts and shown in the screen.

```
if (buttonIndex == 0) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(android.R.id.content,new FirstFragment());
    ft.addToBackStack("added first");
    ft.commit();
} else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
    FragmentTransaction ft1 = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ft1.replace(android.R.id.content,new SecondFragment());
    ft1.setTransition(ft1.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft1.addToBackStack("added second");
    ft1.commit();
}
```

Now you see what is happening.But here is my question.
I click the first and the second button and both fragments are added in the 
stack. No problem:). But if I click let's say the second button 3 times,
then the corresponding fragment will run 3 times as well. Meaning that 
I have to click the back button 3 times so as to go back in the first fragment.

Is this supposed to be happening?

Regards,
Theo.

Comment: if you dont want new instances to be stacked each time you click the button then dont create new instances and add to backstack. there is actually no hard and fast rule about it. if you have data in the previous fragment that the user want to go back to i.e. each successive fragment is related to the previous fragment then you should stack them, else if they are unrelated do not stack them.

Comment: use `fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE); `

Comment: @ BOUTERBIAT Qualid. I just tried. The fragment still runs 3 times,but instead of going in the previous one,I go back in the main activity screen.

Answer (score 2):

You can [add a tag while add/replace](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.support.v4.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String)) a fragment. Then u should check if the same fragment is added once. if yes then remove the existing one.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FirstFragment");
if (prev != null) {
    ft.remove(prev);
}
ft.replace(android.R.id.content,new FirstFragment(),"FirstFragment");
ft.addToBackStack("added first");
ft.commit();
```

A [good example](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) is shown here in DialogFragment implementation

Comment: Thank you for taking some time to answer,but I still have the same problem:(

Comment: did u add the same functions to second fragment as well?

Comment: Yeap. I did exactly the same thing for the second fragment as well.